# "Low memory" warning shows up 5 minutes into game, and crashes game

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I've been (trying to) play *Grand Theft Auto V* on the PC after purchasing it on Steam for the past week in Windows 8.1. But every time I go to play the game, about 5 minutes in, the game will go to a black screen, and Windows throws up a message about being low on memory:

> Close programs to prevent information loss — Your computer is low on memory. Save your files and close these programs: [...]

[image: Screenshot of error message: Close programs to prevent information loss - Your computer is low on memory. Save your files and close these programs: [...]]

The game then won't resume. The thing is, I have boatloads of RAM. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching other gaming forums (none of them as good as this site) I found two threads of people complaining about this issue, and the one thing they all had in common was that they all had an SSD as their primary drive, and the game installed on a secondary drive.

The suggested solution was to disable the Windows page file from your SSD and re-allocate it to a different drive. It sounds nuts, but I did it anyway:

I used the instructions [from this Super User question](https://superuser.com/a/237821/3171). I moved the page file off my SSD and onto another drive (not the drive that GTA-V was installed to though).

And, hey presto. Game works great. I don't know why this would be an issue, as moving the page file off the SSD seems counter-intuitive, but it worked.